# Press button leaves app after removing it from task manager

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using deeplink from email to my app.
When user clicks inside email, He navigates to fragment.Everything works fine, except when I manually remove app from task manager.When I remove it and click deep link it is fine, but when I press back button app exits.

I think there is some problem with stack or lifecycle of my app.
When user remove app from task manager and open from email I want to accomplish that he can press back button and go to previous activity.

I am using one activity as entry point for all my deeplinks, and here is intent inside that activity:

```
  @Override public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    if (intent.getData() != null){
      String pathPart = String.valueOf(Uri.parse(intent.getData().getPathSegments().get(0)));
      if(pathPart.contains("passwordrecovery")){
        intent.setClass(getContext(), ForgotPasswordResetActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
      }

    }
```

Inside my fragment I am parsing intent:

```
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        Uri data = Uri.parse(intent.getData().getPath());
        dataEmail = String.valueOf(Uri.parse(data.getPathSegments().get(1)));
        dataVerification = String.valueOf(Uri.parse(data.getLastPathSegment()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually remove app, the app will get closed and there will be no previous activity. And then if you open it from mail it will launch only fragment and in your back press it will close as there is no previous activity.

You can start another activity through intent.Include this intent in OnBackPress method.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //call the intent here
    }
```

Comment: My fragment is connected to activity, so it will launch blank activity with fragment.I need to call intent inside onStart because I need to parse data and set path to string.Does my old activity stay inside stack when i remove it from task manager? thanks man @Nainal

Comment: No. when you remove it from task manager your all activity gets destroyed